# how to aggregate the following in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have two vectors, `v` and `w`, in MATLAB, both of the same length.

I want to create a sparse matrix `A` of size `max(v) x max(w)` such that `A(i,j)` equals the number of times the pair `[i,j]` appears in `v` and `w`.

Basically, it is something very similar to `A(v,w) = 1`.

This would be correct if there were no repetitions, i.e. if there is no pair `(i,j)` that appears more than once together in `v` and `w`.

But I do have repetitions, and I am not sure how to elegantly accommodate for them.

Note: `v` and `w` are very long. The values they have are about 100 smaller than their length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is simply

```
M = sparse(v, w, ones(size(v)));
```

Matlab will take the cumulative sum.